# Connection does not support reading schema information for 'sql server' DBMS

Tags: sql-server, yii2, odbc

I tried to define SQL Server connection via `ODBC` in `Yii2` but this error occurred:

> Connection does not support reading schema information for 'sql server' DBMS

```
return [
  'components' => [
    'ms_db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'driverName' => 'SQL Server',
        'dsn' => 'odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=192.168.1.120;Database=test;',
        'username' => 'sa',
        'password' => '123',
    ]
```

Comment: Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#db-connection

Answer (score 0):

You have not **sql server** driver,driverName must be a valid service name. Like this :

```
'driverName' => 'mysql',
'dsn' => 'odbc:Driver={MySQL};Server=localhost;Database=test',
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Yii2 wants to read the database schema with something like:

```
   $this->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table`");
```

If it is true, the database user needs the privileges to work with [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql) queries...